# Form success msg disappearing after submitting

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

So right after you submit the form a success msg appears at the bottom and then disappears. How do I stop the success msg from disappearing and please explain what is causing this, I'm learning JavaScript and I want simple explanations please!. [Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/ivanbar/pen/jyEoBm)

PS: I figured a way to make the msg stay after submitting by returning false in the else statement, however I fear this will stop the form from submitting?

Html

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" /><br />
  <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="phone number"/><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/><br />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function validateForm() {
  var n = document.myform.name.value;
  var p = document.myform.number.value;
  var e = document.myform.email.value;

  if (n === '' || n === null) {
    alert("please enter your name!");
    return false;
  } else if (p === '' || p === null) {
    alert("please enter your number!");
    return false;
  } else if (e === '' || e === null) {
    alert("please enter your email!");
    return false;
  }else if(p.length <= 7){
     alert("Please enter a valid phone number!");
     return false;
  }else{
    var msg = "Thank you! your info has been sent!";
    var el = document.createElement('p');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(msg);
    el.appendChild(textNode);
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are not using `action='somepage.php'` in a form, the data is submitted in the current page itself. The page refreshes and the msg variable does not remain in that page anymore.

I would suggest you to create a session variable (using Ajax or something) that contains the message. When the page reloads check if the session variable exists.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>".S_SESSION['msg']."</div>";
}
```

---

Another way is to send the data to the server using Ajax and validate the data there. After validation, it will return the message according to success or failure. Then, you can show the data on your page. In this process, the page does not refresh. Something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "processForm.php",
    data: {
        name: n,
        number: p,
        email: e
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("message_area").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```